# How to approach unfamiliar algorithms (kth element of merged sorted arrays)

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I was recently assigned the homework problem of finding the kth element of a merged set of sorted distinct arrays in O(lgk) time. There are plenty of solutions online that I've had to reference in order to get this done. What annoys me is that I had to reference them in the first place. How do you approach a problem like this? I would like to be able to develop novel algorithms and make them more efficient. Do I just need to grind leetcode to learn a million approaches to things? I understand divide and conquer at a basic level, but figuring out how it applies here was completely beyond me. I wrote out an approach that would work in O(k) time, but that didn't help.

The problem in detail:

> Suppose you have two separate sorted arrays of numbers, A[1 ... m] and B[1 ... n], where all the numbers in A and B are distinct. Given an integer k where 1 ≤ k ≤ m + n, design an algorithm that finds the kth smallest element in the merge of arrays A and B in O(lg k) time.

Comment: If you do enough leetcode easy questions, you will have the algorithmic skill to solve it. For the O(N) it's clearly a two pointer problem. Start two pointers at the beginning of each array, advance whichever pointer is pointing at a smaller number, k-1 times. At the end it will be pointing at the kth smallest.

Comment: @SatbirKira Yeah, the O(k) solution was really simple to come up with. Its the application of divide and conquer for the O(lgk) here that really got me. I hate leetcode and grinding algorithms, and am kinda hoping there are ways to improve my knowledge outside of that. But it looks like I might have to go through a bunch of them when I have time.

Comment: Leetcode is pretty much the only way to develop a higher level of algorithmic thinking. It won't come from university. Try cracking the coding interview first before doing the leetcode grind which will take some months.